# How to query 3 tables to 1 table data collecting by eloquent relationship feature by 1 Model and 1 Controller

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

Here is my default query. I want to convert Eloquent query

This is TransferController.php

```
public function index()
    {
        return Transfer::with(['employee','new_office', 'old_office','designation'])
                        ->orderby('id', 'desc')
                        ->get();
    }
```

Here is my Model Transfer.php

```
class Transfer extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'transfers';
    protected $fillable = [
        'employee_id','order_date','join_date','old_office_id', 'new_office_id',
    ];

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function employee(){
        //return $this->belongsToMany(Employee::class);
        return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class, 'employee_id');
    }
    public function new_office(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Office::class, 'new_office_id');
    }
    public function old_office(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Office::class, 'old_office_id');
    }

    public function designation(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Designation::class, 'employees','id', 'designation_id', 'employee_id');
        //I want to convert this query by eloquent feature.
        // return DB::table('designations')
        //     ->join('employees', 'designations.id', '=', 'employees.designation_id')
        //     ->join('transfers', 'employees.id', '=', 'transfers.employee_id')
        //     ->select('designations.*')
        //     ->get();
    }
}
```

I cant understand belgongToMany or hasOneThrough is perfect query
designation() function is not working but others functionalities are fine

Comment: show your migration file.

Comment: **transfers** table here
`Schema::create('transfers, function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('employee_id');
            $table->string('order_date');
            $table->string('join_date');
            $table->unsignedInteger('old_office_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('new_office_id');
        });`

Comment: **employees** table here
`Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('fatname');
            $table->unsignedInteger('designation_id');
            $table->string('rank')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedInteger('office_id');
            $table->string('join_date');
            $table->string('phone')->nullable();
            $table->string('address')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedInteger('active')->default(1);
        });
`

Comment: **designations** table here
`Schema::create('designations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->unsignedInteger('seniority');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
`

Comment: **offices** table here
`Schema::create('offices', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('code');
            $table->string('address');
            $table->string('unit_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });`